# WCF Silverlight Game Lobby

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am trying to create a turnbased game with Silverlight and WCF Duplex. But I could not do more than a login page. I'm stuck and all of your suggestions/helps would be greatly appreciated.

I have some questions regarding with my architecture.

1. Is it a good way to host my (WCF Polling Duplex) GameService on IIS or should I make a console application and serve the methods?
2. I am calling 2 methods in my home page. 1st LoginAsync and once 1st is completed I'm calling the 2nd GetLoggedInPlayersAsync. But I'm getting errors which I could not figure out.

here what I have so far

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="", CallbackContract=typeof(IGameClient), SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
// [DeliveryRequirements(RequireOrderedDelivery=true)]
public interface IGameService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
    bool Login(Player player);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=false)]
    void Logout();

    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Player> GetLoggedInPlayers();
}  

public interface IGameClient
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void NotifyNewUserConnected(Player player);
}

    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client = Helpers.Extensions.GetGameServiceClient();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Home_Loaded);

        client.GetLoggedInPlayersCompleted += new EventHandler<GetLoggedInPlayersCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetLoggedInPlayersCompleted);
        client.NotifyNewUserConnectedReceived += new EventHandler<NotifyNewUserConnectedReceivedEventArgs>(client_NotifyNewUserConnectedReceived);
        client.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(client_LoginCompleted);

    }

    void Home_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // get the player
        if (Player == null)
        {
            SignInWindow window = new SignInWindow();
            window.Show();

            Player = new Player
            {
                PlayerName = window.txtName.Text
            };

            window.Closed += new EventHandler(window_Closed);


        }
    }
```

Comment: have you checked AutoResetEvents object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx